# xargs: argument line too long

Tags: iptables, xargs

When I run below line in a shell script:

```
/sbin/iptables-save -t filter | 
grep -- "-A INPUT" | 
grep -v "fail2ban-\|f2b-" | 
sed -e "s#^-A#apply_rule /sbin/iptables -D#g" | 
xargs -0 echo -e "`declare -f apply_rule`\n" | 
/bin/bash
```

All it does is checking

```
-A INPUT -s IP -j DROP
```

rule in `iptables-save`.

Say,

```
-A INPUT -s 198.55.114.215 -j DROP
```

Then convert it to `Delete` version and pass to `xargs`

```
apply_rule /sbin/iptables -D INPUT -s 198.55.114.215 -j DROP
```

But I have `2000` `-A` rules in `iptables-save` and when I try to run it, above line throws an error:

```
xargs: argument line too long
```

​I checked limits and

```
echo $(( $getconf ARG_MAX
```

result is:

```
2621440
```

This error does not occur when there `1000` `-A` rules, but `2000` `-A` rules in `iptables-save` creates this issue.

Actual error is line is:

```
xargs -0 echo -e "`declare -f apply_rule`\n"
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: All of your pipeline is processing newline-separated data until `xargs` where `-0` tells `xargs` to expect nul-separated input.

Comment: But it runs without any error if there are 1000 rules. After a limit, I hit xargs limit. 2621440 seems to be pretty big to hit but xargs complains somehow. What do yıu recommend?

Comment: Did you try removing the `-0`?

Comment: Yes I removed the `-0`. It gives error. It tries to split by space. So command not found error occurs. Because `-A INPUT -s 198.55.114.215 -j DROP` contains space `-0` is necessary I suppose to handle spaces.

Comment: Ugh: I forgot that xargs defaults to space-separated.  You need newline-separated.  In place of `xargs -0`, try ` xargs -n1 -d '\n'`

Comment: Thank you so much John for your help. Works perfectly now. Please add as an answer so that I can accept it. But would you mind explaining the answer to me please? I am not pretty at shell scripting. As I see, you separate by new line and process each line. Did `xargs -0` try to run whole pipe line at one go instead?

Comment: Very good!  And, answer added. _"Did xargs -0 try to run whole pipe line at one go instead?"_  Yes.  Because the input to xargs contained no nuls, it treated all of it as just one argument

Comment: Thanks John. Now it works perfect. But this script belongs to actually to `Plesk` for firewall reloading. The script first deletes the `iptables-save` rules by this `xargs` line and then adds the new rules. I want to ask `xargs -0` is a mistake or deliberate action? Now your method works OK but when I check the pipeline it adds `apply_rule` function definition before every iteration line. But that old problematic `xargs -0`, only adds the function definition to the top of pipeline and appends the delete rules. But it creates argument too long error.

Comment: I know your method works it will be great if we can only add function definition once so that we can get some performance efficiency. Deleting 2000 rules takes time because. What do you recommend?

Comment: I could prepend function declaration to the top of stdin after `sed` by `(echo -e "\`declare -f apply_rule\`\n" && cat)`. I think I can remove `xargs` completely and simply pass `stdin` to `bin/bash` this way, right?

Comment: I am not familiar with Plesk so I hesitate to answer.  From what I see here, your suggestion sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the pipeline:

```
/sbin/iptables-save -t filter | 
grep -- "-A INPUT" | 
grep -v "fail2ban-\|f2b-" | 
sed -e "s#^-A#apply_rule /sbin/iptables -D#g" | 
xargs -0 echo -e "`declare -f apply_rule`\n" | 
/bin/bash
```

`iptables` generates a list of rules, one rule per line.  In other words, each rule is separated by a newline character, `\n`.  With the options as shown, the `grep` and `sed` commands are processing their input one line at a time.  In other words, they are also expecting newline-separated input and producing newline-separated output.  `xargs -0` however is expecting nul-separated input.  Since the output of the commands that preceded contain no nul-characters, `xargs` tries to read all of its stdin in at once as a single item.  That is why it generates the error message "argument line too long".

The solution is to tell `xargs` to expect newline-separated input.  To do that, we add the option `-d '\n'`.  However, we also want it to process only one line at a time.  To do that, we need to specify `-n1`.  Putting this all together:

```
/sbin/iptables-save -t filter | 
grep -- "-A INPUT" | 
grep -v "fail2ban-\|f2b-" | 
sed -e "s#^-A#apply_rule /sbin/iptables -D#g" | 
xargs -n1 -d '\n' echo -e "`declare -f apply_rule`\n" | 
/bin/bash
```

#### Documentation

From `man xargs`:

> **-d** delim 
>  Input items are terminated by the specified character. 
>   Quotes and backslash are not special; every character in the input is
>   taken literally.  Disables the end-of-file string, which is treated
>   like any other argument.  This can be used when  the  input  consists 
>   of  simply  newline-separated items, although it is almost always
>   better to design your program to use --null where this is  possible. 
>   The specified delimiter may be a single character, a C-style character
>   escape such as \n, or an  octal  or  hexadecimal
>                 escape code.  Octal and hexadecimal escape codes are understood as for the printf command.   Multibyte characters are not
>   supported.
>
> **-n** max-args
>   Use at most max-args arguments per command
>   line.  Fewer than max-args arguments will be used if the size (see the
>   -s  option)  is  exceeded, unless the -x option is given, in which case xargs will exit.